# PHP Headless Chromium - How to save img to file?

Tags: php, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I would like to use PHP Headless Chromium to automatically login to some account and download images from `<img src="...">` elements.

Loading the page and finding the `img` elements is no problem. However, there does not seem to be an easy way to download / save the image to disk?

Since the page has already been loaded the image should already be available. But how to access it?

Of course I can read the url from the `src` attribute but I cannot simply download it because this would require re-authentication, etc.

I found some questions about this topic which are several years old and use some injected JS to get the image. Is this still the way to go today?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to network activity... Using the Network.responseReceived event, you'd get the response object. Filter out the responses that are for css and other resources and then you get the images of the page.

You may end up with all images like logo and stuff and not just the images you were looking for. But you can cross-check the URL of the response to see if it fits with an image src that you want.

This way will allow you to not re-download the images twice, one by chromium and one by your tool. But it is a bit more code than just grabbing the URL from the SRC of the images. Also, about the re-authentication problem you are having, this is certainly just due to the fact you are not sending the credentials with your second request. Try copying as best as possible the request that chromium does. This includes adding the cookies, maybe other headers too?